# Bootstrap accordian style table - show/hide all

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

I have a table that is set up like an accordion where when a row is clicked it displays a div underneath that row. Clicked again it hides it.

I would like to create a button that allows the user to expand all or hide all.

```
var showing = true;
$('#expandList').click(function () {
    if(showing) {
        $(".collapse").collapse("hide");
        showing = false;
    } else {
        $(".collapse").collapse("show");
        showing = true;
    }
});
```

The hide portion works, the show does not. Also how would I detect if any are collapsed to properly keep the showing variable updated.

Comment: please put up a fiddle

Comment: Here is a fiddle, working fine on Firefox (linux) http://www.bootply.com/R1NAKNeig9

Comment: Share your html code too